# How to use reporting and statistics capabilities for blog post using django

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)


class BlogModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blog = models.TextField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Blog: {self.blog_title}"



class CommentModel(models.Model):
    your_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    blog = models.ForeignKey('BlogModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment by Name: {self.your_name}"
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import BlogModel,CommentModel



class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('blog_title', 'status','created_at','updated_at')
    list_filter = ('status',)
    search_fields = ('blog_title', 'content',)

admin.site.register(BlogModel, PostAdmin)

admin.site.register(CommentModel)
```

I created a simple blog post website with comments and I want to create reports and on the admin panel I have to see how to achieve this.
Like how many posts are created and how many have comments and how many post are draft and published

I checked this module but I don't understand how to implement it https://pypi.org/project/django-reports-admin/

Answer (score 0):

You already have most of this, by using PostAdmin. The list_display already shows you how many posts are published/draft, and the change list has filters for that as well.
To show the comment count, simply add that to list_display:
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('blog_title', 'status', 'comment_count', 'created_at', 'updated_at')

```
def comment_count(self, obj):
    return obj.commentmodel_set.count()
comment_count.short_description = 'Comment count'
```

This thus defines a custom method on the PostAdmin, that displays the comment count as a column, and gives it a user-friendly name as column header.
You can expand this with more statistics if you like. The Django admin is highly customizable.

Note: model names should be in CamelCase, so BlogModel and CommentModel should be Blog and Comment respectively.